# Alias folder in ColdFusion2016

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I’ve just installed ColdFusion2016, using its built-in websever. I have a project, foo, I’ve imported to wwwroot. It has the structure /wwwroot/foo/src/index.cfm. I want to be able to browse to http://localhost/foo/. I have added in the sever.xml an alias:

`<Context path="/" docBase="<cf_home>\wwwroot" WorkDir="<cf_home>\runtime\conf\Catalina\localhost\tmp" aliases="/foo=<cf_home>\wwwroot\foo\src"></Context>`

When I goto http://localhost/foo/ I get a directory listing for foo. I can see the page from http://localhost/foo/src. How do I configure the server for http://localhost/foo/ to point to src?

Comment: can you please use .htaccess??

Comment: Do you have an example of how this is done? And why would this be preferred over the server.xml?

Comment: Why don't you move all the items in `src` folder to `foo`?

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I don't want to do that because, I have a test folder off foo for my unit tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ColdFusion 2016 uses Tomcat 8 which deprecated and removed the method of using the `aliases` attribute. You now want to use `<Resources>` and `<PreResources>` to do the equivalent.

*Below is the conversion of your example code:*

```
<Context path="/" docBase="cf_home\wwwroot" workDir="cf_home\runtime\conf\Catalina\localhost\tmp">
      <Resources>
          <PreResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet" base="cf_home\wwwroot\foo\src"  webAppMount="/foo" />
      </Resources>
</Context>
```

**On a similar note:** I wrote a blog article about a semi-related scenario, that uses the same feature for "aliasing", when CF2016 was released - [Changing the Location of the ColdFusion 2016 Webroot](http://tonyjunkes.com/blog/changing-the-location-of-the-coldfusion-2016-webroot)

Comment: Thank you. That solved my problem. The blog posting was very helpful too.